# rails edit helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, edit, helper

I want to ask in rails about URI helpers, in action edit for example: 
we used Helper method: `edit_movie_path(@movie)`, (suppose @movie is instance variable)so the corresponding Restful Route will be

```
GET /movies/id/edit
```

I confused about how it passes id! as we passed @movie (we did not pass id)?

Answer (score 2):

Rails leverages polymorphism. Every object gets `to_param` method ([here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-to_param)). `ActiveRecord::Base` overrides it to return record `id`, see [these api docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param). Url helpers then rely on the fact that everything can be turned into param with `to_param`

Answer (score 0):

A movie has an id, used by the helper to construct the route string.